# what is the original command to create a file?

Tags: files, history

we can create a file by a lot of commands:

```
cat > foo.txt

echo 'This is a test' > foo.txt

touch foo.txt

vi foo.txt (or any text-editor)
```

my questions are:

- What is the original command to create a file when they first created Linux (Unix)?
- Is there any differences if I used any of the command above to create a new file?

Comment: The most basic command in Unix to create a file is the system call `creat(2)`, or `open(2)`; they in turn are used by lots of programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Linux does not log which processes access a file (because of the cost in performance and storage). If such logging is active then you could look up what caused the first access.

There is no difference in the resulting file if different programs put the same content into it. Different processes may have different UIDs and different primary groups resulting in different file ownership.